# How can I show that $\frac{\exp\left({-\frac{tx}{1-t}}\right)}{1-t}$ is the generating function for the Laguerre polynomials

Tags: special-functions, generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

How do I show that
$$\frac{\exp\left({-\frac{tx}{1-t}}\right)}{1-t}  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k n! x^k }{(k!)^2 (n-k)!} \right ) \cdot  \frac{t^n}{n!} $$
So far, I tried (assuming $|t|<1$)
$$\frac{\exp\left({-\frac{tx}{1-t}}\right)}{1-t}  = \exp \left( - x \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{n+1} \right )\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n  = \prod_{m=0}^\infty  \exp\left( -xt^{m+1} \right )\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$$ 
How to collect $t^n$ from here on??

**ADDED**:: How to show that the above expression is the generating function for [Laguerre polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html)?

Comment: `Laguerre`. $ $

Comment: yes ... sorry for misnomer :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula has an erroneous $n!$ in the denominator.

Using the identity

$$\frac{1}{(1-t)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{n} \frac{1}{1-t}$$

for $n \geqslant 0$, we compute

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\exp \left(\frac{-tx}{1-t}\right)}{1-t} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-tx)^k}{k!}\frac{1}{(1-t)^{k+1}}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-tx)^k}{(k!)^2} \left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-tx)^k}{(k!)^2} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}t^{n-k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k n! x^k}{(k!)^2(n-k)!}t^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k n! x^k}{(k!)^2(n-k)!}\right)t^n
\end{align}$$

changing the order of summation, which is legitimate since the double series converges absolutely (for $\lvert t\rvert < 1$).

Comment: I guess the third identity in the second formula needs more details? It is a infinite sum, the differentiation may not be computed term by term.